# NSImage info to NSString

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstring, nsimage

I've got an NSImage that outputs it's properties with NSLog:

```
myImage: <NSImage 0x7fb0d14107c0 Size={298, 297} Reps=(
         "NSBitmapImageRep 0x7fb0d2205fd0 Size={298, 297}
         ColorSpace=Device RGB colorspace BPS=8 BPP=32
         Pixels=298x297 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=2
         CurrentBacking=<CGImageRef: 0x7fb0d200c1f0> CGImageSource=0x7fb0d2409960"
```

How can I take that information and put it into an NSArray or NSString? (for example: Size, ColorSpace, etc.)

I tried the following:

```
NSImage *myImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];

[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]
  setIcon: myImage
  forFile: targetPath
  options: 0];

  NSLog(@"myImage: %@",myImage);

  NSString *imageInfo = myImage;
  NSArray *chunks = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];

  // last two lines = incompatible pointer types initializing to NSImage
```

Comment: Why don't you save an image as NSData?

Comment: `NSString* imageInfo = myImage.description;` and parse away.  And, of course, some of the attributes can be referenced using methods of NSImage.  (It does need to be noted that `description` is not guaranteed to remain unchanged, so you're best off to use other methods.)

Comment: @ElTomato, I tried using NSData and got the same incompatible pointer error.

Comment: NSString *imageInfo = myImage; doesn't make any sense , how can u assign image to a string. Instead it shd be NSString *imageInfo = [myImage description];

Comment: @HotLicks, That seems to work. please post as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: @turbo - Yes, you're right.

Comment: Yes, to get that string for programmatic access, `-description` is the right approach. But don't – please don't – parse that for anything meaningful. All of that information is accessible through the methods of `NSImage`, `NSImageRep`, and its subclasses (especially `NSBitmapImageRep`).

Comment: @KenThomases, This is for my own purposes really, but always good to know the right way of doing things - thanks